# Jumping onto a platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D platform game in Untiy for android and i am having some issues with a section of code i have. When i jump onto a platform the first time i can land onto the platform but when i jump again i fall through the platform. i have it so the box collider is inactive if the player is less then the height of the platform and active when the player is higher then the platform. I thought the box collider was to small and it was just missing the collider so i have tried different sizes of colliders and i have tried adjusting different heights at which it activates. Also when i set the height to low the player does a double jump. So what am i doing wrong?

```
public class Rock : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private BoxCollider2D platform;
    private PlayerScript player;

    public float height;

    void Awake() {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerScript>();
        platform = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    void Start () {
        platform.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(player.transform.position.y > height){
            platform.enabled = true;
        } else if(player.transform.position.y < height){
            platform.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here. What exactly is height? is it the height of the rock or is it the position of rock in world-space? Can't you just do something like, `player.transform.position.y > transform.position.y` ?

Comment: height is the is the position of the rock in worldspace.

Comment: when i do ' player.transform.position.y > transform.position.y' the player does a super jump not something that i want

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in your PlayerScript.

Comment: you were right it was in my player script. i had                                              'void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision target) {                                                                  grounded = false;                                                                                                 }'                                                                                                                 and this was cousing it do to a double jump i had this on there to make sure it stayed on the walking animation instead of the jump animation

Comment: @Papaskippy If you were able to solve your problem, it might be worth posting your own answer with the fixed code and an explanation of what was wrong in your original approach.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're not covering the case where `player.transform.position.y == height`?
I can see that you're checking for greater / smaller than `height` but not equality. This could lead to unwanted behavior like the one you're describing.

Let me know if this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code actually worked. The issue ended up being in my playerscript where I had added a chunk of code where I was  having a bug if you held the jump button down the player would get stuck in the jump animation.

```
    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D target) {
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        grounded = true;
        anim.SetBool("Jump",false);
    }

}


public void Jump () {
    if(grounded){
        grounded = false;   
        anim.SetBool("Jump",true);
        myBody.velocity = new Vector2(myBody.velocity.x, 0);
        myBody.AddForce( new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }
}
```

After some troubleshooting and going and removing pieces of code trying to see why I doubled jump I finally came across this piece then when I was trying with the touch controls instead of with the keyboard I noticed I am not actually able to hold the jump button down like you can with a keyboard so I didn't really need this piece of code. So I was my own worst enemy this time.